# HashMaps - WebElements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please assist me in trying to achieve the following but using a `HashMap`. I am not an expert at using `HashMap`s.

**Code with Array**

```
WebElement xmlResponse = iframeElements9.findElement(By.name("currentContactInfo.messageRecord.resMsg"));
WebElement xmlRequest = iframeElements9.findElement(By.name("currentContactInfo.messageRecord.reqMsg"));
WebElement[] listOfElements = {xmlRequest,xmlResponse};

FileHandlers outputToTextFile = new FileHandlers();
ConvertOutputToXML convert = new ConvertOutputToXML();

String textAreaValue=null;
String FileName =  null;
org.w3c.dom.Document xmlOutput = null;
//iterating through the Array, this works fine but would like to achieve the same using hashmap
for (int j=0;j<listOfElements.length; j++){
   textAreaValue = listOfElements[j].getText(); //using the Hashmap I would like to invoke getText
   FileName = outputToTextFile.writeToFile(textAreaValue);// i then write this output to a file
   convert.ReadTextFile(FileName);
   xmlOutput = (org.w3c.dom.Document) convert.convertToXML(textAreaValue);
}
```

**Code with HashMap**

```
HashMap<String, WebElement> XMLData = new HashMap<>();
XMLData.put("reqMsg",xmlRequest);
XMLData.put("resMsg",xmlResponse);
for (int i = 0; i < XMLData.size(); i++)
{
 System.out.println(XMLData.get(i).getText());  //null pointer exception is what I get
}
```

Ideally i would like to use the key "reqMsg" or "resMsg" to then write the output from the text area to a file, each message in it own file, using the Array works fine but just need the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get HashMap value using get()

```
String val = (String)XMLData.get("reqMsg");
```

You should use key in the XMLData.get(i)

That's why you get null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

To get a value from an `HashMap` you should use the `get()` method accessing with a key.
To access those elements you should do the following:

```
XMLData.get("your_key")
```

In your case something like this:

```
HashMap<String, WebElement> XMLData = new HashMap<>();
XMLData.put("reqMsg",xmlRequest);
XMLData.put("resMsg",xmlResponse);

 System.out.println(XMLData.get("reqMsg").getText()); 
 System.out.println(XMLData.get("resMsg").getText());
```

Then you can write datas to a file.

Comment: If you need more information add clarification here :)

Comment: If it was useful, remember to accept the answer and/or vote up with the up arrow in the left side of it.